# Regex split on string after 2 digits

Tags: java, regex, string

How can i split my string into valid currency or double formats. I know all values only have 2 decimals.

Example

```
String line = "3850.439.00 0.00 260.00 23";
```

thus `3850.439.00` is incorrect and needs to be split.

I have this

```
String[] arr = line.split("\\d+.(\\.\\d{2})");
```

but the results are incorrect - `9.00 0.00   23`

Required result would be `3850.43 9.00 0.00 260.00 23`

Comment: you might also want to split at every space?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than `split` you can use this negative lookbehind regex to get all valid matches from your input:

```
(?<!\.)\d+(?:\.\d{2})?
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sy7IZB/1)

`(?<!\.)` is negative lookbehind to assert a failure when preceding character is DOT.

**Java Code:**

```
final String regex = "(?<!\\.)\\d+(?:\\.\\d{2})?";
final String string = "3850.439.00 0.00 260.00 23";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
}
```

[regex reference for Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Really great answer, worked and thanks for the quick reply